# HTML / CSS - Dynamically abbreviate text based on screen width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to abbreviate short timestamp phrases based on the resolution of the screen.

For example, here are some phrases with its respective abbreviation.

"1 hour ago" => 1h

"2 days ago" => 2d

"40 minutes ago" => 40m

How can I dynamically abbreviate text in a span as the width of the screen shrinks while still being able to determine which letter to concatenate onto the end of the number based on the time keyword (hour/hours, day/days, minute/minutes) in the phrase?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
 let text = "1 hour ago"
 let text2 = "2 days ago"
 let textSplited = text.split(' ')// RESULT -> ARRAY(3) ["1", "hour", "ago"]
 let textSplited2 = text2.split(' ')// RESULT -> ARRAY(3) ["2", "days", "ago"]
 const finalResult = `${textSplited[0]}${textSplited[1][0]}`
 const finalResult2 = `${textSplited2[0]}${textSplited2[1][0]}`
 console.log(finalResult) // RESULT => 1h
 console.log(finalResult2) // RESULT => 2d
```